# Symfony - Attempted to load class "SonataDatagridBundle" from namespace "Sonata\DatagridBundle"?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

At this moment, I use Symfony 4.3, and I don't have any problem in dev.

When I want to install any specific new bundle , i have this error :

```
Attempted to load class "SonataDatagridBundle" from namespace "Sonata\DatagridBundle". Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

I try to install `knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle` with specific version 1.5.2.

composer.json

```
{
  "type": "project",
"license": "proprietary",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "*",
    "doctrine/event-manager": "*",
    "doctrine/orm": "*",
    "doctrine/persistence": "*",
    "friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle": "^2.2",
    "mpdf/mpdf": "^8.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.54",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.12",
    "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/asset": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/console": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/expression-language": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
    "symfony/form": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/http-client": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/intl": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/mailer": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/orm-pack": "*",
    "symfony/process": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/translation": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/twig-bundle": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/twig-pack": "*",
    "symfony/validator": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/web-link": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/yaml": "4.4.*",
    "vich/uploader-bundle": "^1.13",
    "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "1.5.2",
   },
   "require-dev": {
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.3",
    "dompdf/dompdf": "dev-master",
    "symfony/debug-pack": "*",
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "*",
    "symfony/profiler-pack": "*",
    "symfony/test-pack": "*",
    "symfony/var-dumper": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/web-server-bundle": "4.4.*"
    },
   "config": {
    "preferred-install": {
        "*": "dist"
    },
    "sort-packages": true,
    "allow-plugins": {
        "symfony/flex": false
    }
   },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"

    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"replace": {
    "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
    "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
},
"scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
        "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
        "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
    },
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ]
},
"conflict": {
    "symfony/symfony": "*"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony": {
        "allow-contrib": false,
        "require": "4.4.*"
    }
   }
  }
```

I tried a lot of command like :

`composer update`  and then `composer dump-autoload`

also

`composer update vendor/knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle:1.5.2 --with-dependencies`

and

`composer require knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle "^1.5.2"`

but all time the same error.

my bundles.php

```
<?php

return [
    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\MakerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\WebServerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
    Sonata\DatagridBundle\SonataDatagridBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Sonata\CoreBundle\SonataCoreBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Knp\Bundle\SnappyBundle\KnpSnappyBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
    Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Twig\Extra\TwigExtraBundle\TwigExtraBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    FOS\CKEditorBundle\FOSCKEditorBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Vich\UploaderBundle\VichUploaderBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```

I tried also to change and then do `composer dump-autoload`  :

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
 
        }
    },
```

by

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src/"
 
        }
    },
```

but everytime I get the same error.

`When I run composer require or composer update, symfony do update of symfony flex and there is the problem, I ask for a way to update only KnpSnappyBundle without changing anything in vendor?`